# Getting unecessary quotation marks in Python 2

Tags: python

In a whole context of trying to combine 2 APIs, I need to "combine" two functions results so that everything is more organized.

```
def descr():
    return 88
def name():
    return 'Account',descr()
```

When I print name(), I get this ('Account', 88). Problem with that format is that I can't use this result later in my script.

Here is the whole script :

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://proxy6.net/api/xxx/getproxy"

def descr():
    return 88
def name():
    return 'Account',descr()


querystring = {"descr":descr()}

headers = {
    'Cache-Control': "no-cache",
    'Postman-Token': "xxxx"
    }

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)

data = response.json()
for value in data['list'].values():
    host = value['host']
    port = value['port']

url = "https://api.multiloginapp.com/v1/profile/create"

querystring = {"token":"xxx"}

payloadobj = {
    "generateZeroFingerprintsData": True,
    "name": name(),
    "OS": "MacOS",
    "platform": "MacIntel",
    "browserType": "mimic",
    "proxyHost": host,
    "proxyPort": port,
    "proxyIpValidation": False,
    "proxyType": "socks5",
    "maskFonts": True,
    "disablePlugins": True,
    "disableWebrtcPlugin": True,
    "disableFlashPlugin": True,
    "canvasDefType": "noise",
    "hardwareConcurrency": 2,
    "langHdr": "en-US,en;q=0.8",
    "timeZone": "US/Eastern",
    "audio": {
        "noise": True
    },
    "geolocation": {
        "permitType": "block"
    },
    "mediaDevices": {
        "audioInputs": 1,
        "audioOutputs": 1,
        "videoInputs": 1
    },
    "webgl": {
        "noise": True
    },
    "webRtc": {
        "type": "block"
    },
    "shared": False
}

payload = json.dumps(payloadobj)

headers = {
    'Content-Type': "application/json",
    'Cache-Control': "no-cache",
    'Postman-Token': "xxx"
    }

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers, params=querystring)

print(response.text)
```

I want the name value in the JSON query above to be the result of name + descr, but it won't work with that returned format.

Comment: How, *exactly* does it "not work"?

Comment: What is "name + descr" supposed to be __exactly__ ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need.

```
def descr():
    return 88
def name():
    return '{} {}'.format('Account', descr())

print(name())
```

**Output:**

```
Account 88
```

Answer (score 1):

`name()` is returning a tuple object not a string. To return a string you could change it to:

```
def name():
    return "Account {}".format(descr())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python3.6 or later you can:

```
def descr():
    return 88

def name():
    return f"Account {descr()}"
```